# Django rest framework show or hide API objects with checkbox in admin

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

I need to understand how show or hide objects in API serialize by django rest framework.
I set a checkbox in my admin model to set active or inactive the object (true or false)

```
class Video(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.BooleanField('Activate video', default=False, help_text='If is checked show the video in the API')
    ...
```

in my `urls.py` i set

```
from video.models import Video

class VideoAPI(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = [...]

class API_Video(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoAPI
```

Now how can i show or hide objects in the API Json with the checkbox in my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF uses the queryset you provide to populate the JSON response in combination with the fields you provide in serializer's `Meta` class.

So in order to filter out the objects with `status=False` you can simply filter the provided queryset:

```
class API_Video(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Video.objects.filter(status=True)
    serializer_class = VideoAPI
```

you can also call the `get_queryset` method and override it to do more advanced and complex filtering: [DRF - Doc - get_queryset(self)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself)